# Anaconda fresh install broken on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, python, anaconda

I just spent my whole morning trying to understand how to install Anaconda3 to my windows 10. The conclusion, is that he new Anaconda3-2019.07 install is broken.

I had it working fine, but I had some problems with some DLL and pydev/eclipse. I thougth it would be better to do a new fresh install of both.

After a download the Anaconda3-2019.07 installer package from official web site, install it, there are no exe files in the Anaconda3 installed folder. No bin folder, no prompt, no navigator, nothing. Just this:

[Anaconda3 installation folder after installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1a0K.png)

After installing and reinstalling thousand times, I searched all over and couldn't find the answer.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I just installed Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe and it works perfectly. The installation some minutes to finish, unlike the Anaconda3-2019.07 version that installs in seconds and seems haven't done all the needed things...

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue.  The problem for me was my C:/users/name/.condarc file had a problem.  I had a previous install of Anaconda.  If you click on the "details" button in the installer you'll see it copying files.  It actually downloads some files from the internet.  In my case, a misconfigured proxy server meant it couldn't download anything.  The installer finished and reported success, even thought the download failed, thus the almost empty directory with minimal files.